# SQL for selecting single record from duplicates based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL, which picks up one record among the duplicates (if exist), based on highest production volume. A sample input and output:
[image]

If there are duplicate KEYS, in the above example-A-2, it should check the volume, and pickup the record having higher volume(i.e. one with 42 volume in the above example)

Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: What if both rows with the same key have the same volume?

Comment: @Akina: Then we pick up only one of them

Comment: *Then we pick up only one of them* WHAT ONE??? With maximal VALUE? or maybe minimal? or even randomly selected? And - what is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina: Sorry!, I misunderstood your question. If both the rows have different value, but same volume, we will keep both.

Comment: If a KEY has 2 different VALUES, then we check and pickup the one having highest volume. If the volumes are different, we will pickup both the records

Answer (score 0):

try like below using corelated sub query

```
select t1.* from input t1
where t1.volume=( select max(volume) from input t2 where t1.Key=t2.key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Subquery

Select * from Table1 a where Volume=(Select MAX(Volume) from Table1 where [Key]=a.[Key])
order by [Key]